# Gnuplot; iterating over files in directory to print png

Tags: gnuplot

In the directory l250 I have a couple of files. They each start off with "l2_" the part after it is the numerical value. I want to be able to plot what is in the file last.sh for about 300 files. I want to know what will be the way I can iterate over the file and have that be $1 and have the second value be $2.

I was thinking that because the files are in the current directory I can use for. But then I am reading about awk and csv and I don't know what to do. I would like insight on what will be the better way to iterate over a large amount of files rater then putting it in main.sh and running that.

main.sh

```
sh last.sh l2_4 1
sh last.sh l2_5 2
sh last.sh l2_6 3
sh last.sh l2_7 4
.
.
.
```

last.sh

```
gnuplot << EOF
set terminal png
set output "finished/$1.png"
set xlabel "Angs"
set ylabel "Angs"
set title "$1  |  $2 fs "
set zrange [0: 0.00001]
set pm3d map
splot "$1"
EOF
```

I run the following in the command line:

```
$sh main.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

First you generate a list containing all file names with

```
list = system('ls l2_*')
```

which you can then iterate over with `do for ...` (requires gnuplot 4.6):

```
set terminal pngcairo
set xlabel "Angs"
set ylabel "Angs"
set zrange [0: 0.00001]
set pm3d map

list = system('ls l2_*')
i = 1

do for [file in list] {
    set output sprintf('finished/%s.png', file)
    set title sprintf("%s | %d fs", file, i)
    splot file
    i = i + 1
}
```

Comment: Some one more thing, the pattern is 7 - 3 = 4 fs. The propagation starts at l2_3 so in that graph the wave is at 0 fs. It will then continue on. Is there a way to know the value of * and subtract an integer from it and let that be i?  So if * was 10, we know i will be 10 -3 = 7 fs.

Comment: To extract the minimum value of all `*`, use `min = int(system('sed "s/l2_//g"| sort -n | head -1'))`. Maybe you must also pass some options to `ls` or pipe the output throught `sort -n` in order to get the correct ordering of the files.

Comment: plus this may fail if you have more images than the max argument count, use find -type f -name '*.txt'  | wc -l instead